# SELECT * INTO OUTFILE directory

Tags: php, mysql, file-io

I am trying to generate a file from mysql. The I am using is:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/data.txt FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' FROM admin";
```

The code is working fine as I am not getting any error. But the problem is I could not locate where the file is created. Would any body please help me.

I am using a shared hosting.

Thanks

Comment: Show the full code you are using please

Comment: The file name has to be quoted, e.g. - SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'dir/filename'

Comment: Added the [tag:php] tag. `$_SERVER` is a PHP thing

Answer (score 1):

The query should be run like this, I mean it should be quoted.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/data.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' FROM admin";");
```

To successfully run this query you'll need these

1. User must have `FILE` privilege
2. MYSQL server daemon must have write privilege to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/data.txt`. And this directory must be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

you are using shared hosting then good way to connect ftp and get the path of physical working directory, you can get form "pwd" linux command

use that path because at the shared host make some time issue